# Call RelayCommand in WPF-Control from WPF-Windows (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, relaycommand, commandbinding

I have a WPF UserControl with a ViewModel as DataContext. This ViewModel also contains RelayCommands. From the control I can call these commands (e.g. with a button) `<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">Save</Button>`. Now I want to place the control in a window and call the commands from there `<Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=myControl}">Save</Button>`. But this does not work. How can I call a command in a child control in XAML?

Thanks a lot
Markus

Comment: A UserControl is not supposed to set its own DataContext to something like its own, private view model. It should instead get the value of its DataContext by property value inheritance from its parent element, or by a binding like `DataContext="{Binding SubViewModel}"`. The view model should hence be set by the Window, which could then easily use properties of the view model object itself, e.g. those commands.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you in principle. But in this case the control should be released via Com. The control must therefore instantiate the data independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main window has different DataContext and you can't reach this command through it you can write

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SaveCommand, ElementName=myControl}">Save</Button>
```